# VBA to create move instead of moving file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create acopy of excel file in different location with revised name. Below code move the file with revised name instead of copying.

I don't want to remove the file from original location just want to create a copy. Please assist.

```
Dim myFileNameDir As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
myFileNameDir = Sheet1.Range("V9").Value & SPID1 & "\" & ComboBox29.Text
scor = ComboBox29.Text
scor = Replace(scor, ".", "")
MsgBox myFileNameDir

filenz = SPID1 & "_" & Emp1 & "_" & scor & "_" & VBA.Format(Now, "MMddyyyyhmmss AM/PM ")
Dim myfile As String
myfile = Sheet1.Range("V10").Value & filenz & ".xlsx"
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call fso.CopyFile(myFileNameDir, myfile)
```

Comment: What makes you think this is moving the file and not copying? I only ask as `FileSystemObject.CopyFile` **is** for **copying** files, **not** moving them. Perhaps there is further code in your program which deletes the original?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried the FSO copy, but this should do:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("cmd.exe /c  xcopy /y /s """ & Source & """ """ & Dest & """", WindowStyle:=7 , WaitOnReturn:=(your boolean) )
```

with the advantage that you may resume the code asynchroneously.

Answer (score 0):

This copied the file while retaining the original.  It's basically the same code as yours, so as @CLR said - perhaps there is further code in your program which deletes the original?

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox CopyFile("C:\_Test\A\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx", _
                     "C:\_Test\B\Copy Of File.xlsx", False)

End Sub

Function CopyFile(FromFile As String, ToFile As String, Overwrite As Boolean) As Boolean

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    On Error Resume Next
    oFSO.CopyFile FromFile, ToFile, Overwrite
    CopyFile = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

End Function
```